# Writing to file geodatabase table using ArcPy cursor?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, cursor

I wanted to copy a specific row of a table to another new table. So what I did was,

1. copy the data of the row to a particular Array called `c[]`.
2. Write them to a file Geodatabase table called `Dead_T`

I have completed the 1st step. Now I want to do the 2nd step. I have tried the following code for step 2, but it is not working. Can anyone tell me the mistake that I have made here?
(Here **filedname** is one of the names of columns available in the table `Dead_T`)

```
Dead_T='C:\Users\Shanaka\Desktop\TL _HAndling\cad\Cad_Data.gdb\DD_IF'
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(Dead_T, "filedname") as cursor1:
    for row1 in cursor1:
        row1[0] = c[0]
        arcpy.AddMessage ("done")

        cursor1.updateRow(row1)
```

Comment: UPDATE changes an existing row. INSERT creates a new one. Your `c` variable is not defined. Do you really want to clobber every row with the first element of the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you must use an insert cursor here because update cursor work for changing the values of existing rows:

```
# I assume that DT and c are defined, the fieldnames exist in DT and c is a list of list with two item.
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(DT, ("fieldname1","fieldname2")) as cursor:
    for row in c: #take each row of c
        cursor.insertRow(c)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This really helps me. It is working now